# An algebraic property that makes a per-C*-algebra complete

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a normed *-algebra with $\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2$. Suppose that   for every subset S of A, the left annihilator
${\displaystyle \mathrm {Ann} _{L}(S)=\{a\in A\mid \forall s\in S,as=0\}\,}$
is generated as a left ideal by some projection p of A.

Q. Is $A$ norm complete (i.e., an AW*-algebra)?

Comment: How about the subalgebra of those functions in $\ell_\infty({\bf N})$ that take only finitely many values?

Comment: Yes, it is a nice countra-example. Thanks.